# Grails and Quartz on Tomcat: how to gracefully shutdown

Tags: tomcat, grails, quartz-scheduler, shutdown

I have a Grails application with the following `grails-app/conf/QuartzConfig.groovy`:

```
quartz {
    autoStartup = true
    jdbcStore = false
    waitForJobsToCompleteOnShutdown = false
    exposeSchedulerInRepository = false
    interruptJobsOnShutdown = true

    props {
        scheduler.skipUpdateCheck = true
    }
}
```

However every time I shut down Tomcat, there will be a process left hanging which I'll have to kill. According to the above config file this should not happen. Is there another property I should be using to achieve this?

Furthermore upon Tomcat startup I see 10 lines of (for the 10 Quartz threads):

> SEVERE: The web application [/test] appears to have started a thread
>   named [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-5] but has failed to stop it.
>   This is very likely to create a memory leak.

The above also doesn't change with the properties in the config file, which is seemingly related to the hanging process. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How are you shutting down quartz? Do all your jobs respond immediately to interrupts by shutting down?

Comment: @MarkThomas I'm basically shutting down Tomcat. Do I have to manually shut down Quartz before shutdown? I was under the impression that the property `interruptJobsOnShutdown` should do it.

Comment: you can write a service MBean, expose a action and use it to stop the job, rather than force kill.  > Service action may set a flag, which each job can check. >> make scheduler instance accessible to jobs. >>> based on the flag value executing job should be able to stop repeating itself after completing the execution. I will try to put a complete approach to this idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the latest version of the Quartz plugin. We released it a day ago.

Comment: The latest version seems to have solved the problem (at least, it's not longer showing up in the logs)

Comment: sometimes I have the problem with the actual version 1.0.2 of this quartz grails plugin